# Add Table Row Using jQuery - MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom-manipulation

I am currently trying to implement an Add functionality to my page. Currently, the add is already functioning but I have to refresh the page in order for the newly added row to appear on the table.

Please see my codes below:

This is how I generate my table:

```
<table class="webGrid" id="ProductsTable">
<tr>
    <td><strong><span>ProductID</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span>ProductName</span></strong></td>
    <td><strong><span>Price</span></strong></td>
    <td colspan="2"><strong><span>Action</span></strong></td>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in repository.GetAllProducts(ViewData["BranchCode"].ToString()))
{ 
<tr>
    <td><span class="ProductID">@item.ProductID</span></td>
    <td><span class="ProductName">@item.ProductName</span></td>
    <td><span class="Price">@item.Price</span></td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { RecordID = item.RecordID }, new { @class = "editLink" })</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { RecordID = item.RecordID }, new { @class = "editLink" })</td>
</tr>
}
```

Currently, the edit and delete are already functioning well. Below is how I do the edit:

```
function update(data) {
if (data.Success == true) {
    var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");

    parent.find(".ProductID").html(data.Object.ProductID);
    parent.find(".ProductName").html(data.Object.ProductName);
    parent.find(".Price").html(data.Object.Price);
}
else {
    $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
    $("#update-message").show();
}
```

}

Now I am trying to implement an add functionality which is almost the same as the edit jquery i am using. I have tried using the `.append` method unsuccessfully.

---

**EDIT:**

I have tried using the code below for the add. But it doesn't seem to do anything. Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong:

```
    function add(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {

        var rowTemplate = $("#rowTemplate").html();
        var tbl = document.getElementById("ProductsTable");
        var counter = $("#ProductsTable tr").length;
        data.Counter = counter;
        $("#ProductsTable").append(applyTemplate(rowTemplate, data));

    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}

function applyTemplate(template, data) {
    var str = template;
    if ($.isPlainObject(data)) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            var find = new RegExp("\\$1" + index, "ig");
            str = str.replace(/\$/g, "\$1");
            str = str.replace(find, value);
        });
    }
    return str;
}
```

It makes use of a row template such as the following:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="rowTemplate">
        <tr><td><input type="text" id="txtName_$Counter" value="" /></td></tr>
    </script>
```

I just found this solution online but I can't make it to work. I also tried the code below (i just made up based on the edit jquery I have):

```
    function add(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
        parent.find(".ProductID").append(data.Object.ProductID);
        parent.find(".ProductName").append(data.Object.ProductName);
        parent.find(".Price").append(data.Object.Price);
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Right now, this is how my jQuery looks like:

```
function add(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        data = { Counter: 3 };
        $("#rowTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#ProductsTable");
        $('#updateDialog').dialog('close');
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
```

and this is my template:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="rowTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="ProductID"></span></td>
        <td><span class="ProductName"></span></td>
        <td><span class="Price"></span></td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditProduct", new { @class = "editLink" })</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "_DeleteProduct", new { @class = "editLink" })</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Thanks to Sir @Muhammad Adeel Zahid for helping me make the jQuery work to add rows. However, it only adds a new row to my table. What I need now is to make it add the values I have from the `data` object in the `add function` of the jQuery.

I have tried following the tutorial from [THIS LINK](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-working-with-the-official-jquery-templating-plugin/) but I can't seem to make it work. My code is below:

```
function add(data) {
    if (data.Success == true) {
        var prod = $.map(data.results, function (obj, index) {
            return {
                ProductID:  obj.text,
                ProductName: obj.text,
                Price: obj.text
            };
        });

        prod = { Counter: 3 };
        $("#rowTemplate").tmpl(prod).appendTo("#ProductsTable");
        $('#updateDialog').dialog('close');
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").html(data.ErrorMessage);
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Can you post whatever you've tried for the add functionality? Doesn't matter if it doesn't work, it will give us a place to start.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Please see my edits above. :)

Comment: Are you getting any error? You can check with firebug or chrome console.

Comment: i'm not getting any error on both jqueries. and sadly, i'm not really familiar with firebug and chrome console.

Comment: Open your page in Google chrome, do Ctrl+Shift+I and then click the console tab. Now click the add button/link of your page and see if there's anything displayed in the chrome console tab.

Comment: i used the Profiler of IE and this is what I got
`JScript - window script block 3 0.00 0.00 http://localhost:1893/Scripts/Popup.js 56 `
it points to this line of the code:
`$.each(data, function (index, value) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your template code. Please try changing it to

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="rowTemplate">
        <tr><td><input type="text" id="txtName_${Counter}" value="" /></td></tr>
    </script>
```

and then generate html from it like

```
var obj = {Counter:3};
$("#rowTemplate").tmpl(obj).appendTo("#ProductsTable");
```

**Edit**
First I thought you were using jquery template engine and my answer was based on that assumption. you can find how to use templating engine [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-working-with-the-official-jquery-templating-plugin/). Please see that i have also edited the type field in `<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" ...`. Import jquery template js file in your code and leave rest of the things as is. It should work then.
**Edit 2**
Ok that is a different template. Remember you must have unique id for each of your template. That template would look like

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="rowTemplate2">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="ProductID">${ProductId}</span></td>
        <td><span class="ProductName">${ProductName}</span></td>
        <td><span class="Price">${Price}</span></td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditProduct", new { @class = "editLink" })</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "_DeleteProduct", new { @class = "editLink" })</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Note how you add placeholders `${Variable}` in the templates. Now when you need to use the template, you will need a json object with properties matching the variables used in the template. For example to use above template, I would do something like

```
var obj2 = {ProductId:2,ProductName:'First Product', Price: 323};//note the properties of json and template vars match.
$("#rowTemplate2").tmpl(obj2).appendTo("#somecontainer");
```

Comment: hi! thanks for this! but i tried this solution and it gave me this error. `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method` :(

Comment: Are you using jquery templating? which version (jquery and templating engine)?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this! I have made it to work to add a new row. However, it only adds a blank row. Can you help me apply the values I have from the Add Popup Dialog Box into the new row? Please see my Edit above. Thanks a lot.